# Write filter condition inside filter include in StrongLoop

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I write in Node this filter:

```
include: {
relation: 'province',
scope: {
    where: {
        'regionId': 9
    }
}}
```

The filter working properly, the rest api filter that I wrote is like this:

```
filter[include][province][scope][where][regionId]=9
```

I have this error:

> "error": {
>   "name": "Error",
>   "status": 500,
>   "message": "Relation \"scope\" is not defined for Provinces model"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json filter like calling in node, and this is not REST like

```
?filter={"include": {"relation": "province","scope": {"where": {"regionId": 9}}}}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ebrahim! Working properly!

Comment: @J.Doe Cool. Please kindly accept my answer if the problem resolved